# A Nim variant: Number of stones

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

Alice and Bob play the following game. There is one pile of $N$ stones. They take turns to pick stones from the pile, Alice will play first. In each turn, a player can only pick $k$ $(a \le k \le b)$ stones, the player who takes the last stone wins. With what property of $N$, will Alice win?

Comment: Well have you worked out a few simple examples to see what general pattern might hold?

Answer (score 3):

For the game as described, Bob wins if $0 \le N \lt a$ as Alice cannot move.  Alice wins if $a \le N \lt a+b$, as she can leave Bob something in the range $0$ through $a-1$.  The pattern recurs modulo $a+b$, because whoever is winning can make sure two moves remove exactly $a+b$ stones.  So Bob's winning positions are $0 \le N \pmod {a+b} \lt a$ and Alices are $a \le N \pmod {a+b} \le a+b-1$

Answer (score 1):

For any given $a$ and $b$, the set of $N$ for which Alice wins is determined by some congruence conditions on $N$ - in other words, it's a periodic set (with some period depending on $a$ and $b$). For example, if $a=1$, then Alice can win if and only if $N$ is not a multiple of $b+1$. (Her strategy is to leave a multiple of $b+1$ stones for Bob every time he has to play.) [This paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gordon/ysp/nim.pdf) has some discussion and examples in more general situations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the paper link.

Comment: link is not working