# Understanding Nim

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I was going through a problem where we have given $k$ piles from $1$ to $k$ and each pile contains some stones. Now, there is a game in which there are $2$ players, say $A$ and $B$ who removes stones from piles one by one and who removes stone(s) at the end, wins the game and here, restriction is :  for each pile, maximum number of stones he/she can remove is given and minimum number of stones he/she can remove is also given which is $1$. For example, there are $2$ piles, $1$ and $2$, from pile $1$, a person can remove maximum $1$ stone and from pile $2$, a person can remove maximum $2$ stones. Pile $1$ contains total $3$ stones and pile $2$ contains $2$ stones. Now  pair (pile number, number of stones removed) of moves between players can be (1, 1) (2, 2) (1, 1) (1, 1). So, here, player $1$ lost the game. I was applying the approach which is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383987/a-nim-variant-number-of-stones?rq=1)  means player $2$ will try to make $(a+b)$ as $1+2 = 3$ and at the end player $1$ will be remaining, So, he will lost the game. Is my approach Correct ?
  I have tried few examples with the approach given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383987/a-nim-variant-number-of-stones?rq=1) but I didn't get the logic of $(a+b)$. Why he has chosen $(a+b)$ i.e. min+max, not any other value like $(a+1),(a+3)$ etc. Could anyone please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) has a good discussion. If you leave a position where the bitwise XOR of the numbers of counters in all the piles is $0$ you will win.  Your description of the game is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Are you restricted to removing stones from one pile at a time?

Comment: @RossMillikan, I understood the basic nim game where constraints are not there but in case of minimum(a) and maximum number of stones(b), I am not getting the logic of "a+b" means why players are trying to make "a+b" to win the game. I have not taken the course of game theory. So, maybe I am missing something which maybe required to understand it. Anyway, Thanks for the response.

Comment: @saulspatz yes.

Comment: Is your main question "1. Why does the one pile situation follow that $a+b$ rule? I don't understand something in [the answer on that other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/384068/26369)." "2. Assuming I know the strategy for the one pile situation, how could I tackle multiple piles (each with their own $a$ and $b$ values)?", or "3. something else"? If 1, maybe put a comment on that answer, or look up any words you don't know, or rewrite your question so you don't bring up multiple piles. If 2, without any game theory you sort of have to have the right guess as to how to handle it...

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks!. I didn't put comment there because that answer was old, so, I might not get the reply there.

Comment: You never clearly said there was a fixed maximum number of stones you can remove from one pile.  As you accepted saulspatz answer, that must be true.  Please make the question clear.  -1  It is important to clearly state the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider a game with only one pile.

If you are allowed to take from $1$ through $s$ stones from the pile, and you leave $s+1$ stones, you have won, for your opponent can't pick up all the stones, and he must reduce the number of stones to $s$ or less, and then you pick up all remaining stones.  Similarly, if you leave $2(s+1)$ stones, then whatever your opponent does, you can get to $s+1$ stones, and win.  The winning positions are of the form $c(s+1),\ c=0,1,2,\dots$.

It's not hard to show that the Grundy number of a pile with $k$ stones is the remainder of $k$ on division by $s+1$.

To evaluate the Grundy number of a position with multiple piles, take the nim sum of the Grundy numbers of the piles, as in nim.

Comment: It seems each pile's minimum isn't 1, but some arbitrary number. I think if you can remove all numbers of stones between $a$ and $b$ inclusive, with $a<b$, then the Grundy number is $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n\%(a+b)}{a}\right\rfloor$ where by $\%$ I mean the remainder.

Comment: @MarkS. No, the OP says,  "minimum number of stones he/she can remove is also given which is $1$."

Comment: @MarkS Your expression for the Grundy numbers in the more general game looks reasonable, but I haven't proved it.  have you?

Comment: Thank you. @saulspatz and Mark S

Comment: @saulspatz Here is a sketch: For fewer than $a$ stones, no moves are available, so the sequence (starting from $0$ stones) starts with $a$ zeros. If there were no maximum $b$, then we would have $\lfloor n/a\rfloor$ because every $a$ stones added lets us reach a higher Grundy value. However, because of the maximum, when we hit $n=a+b$, we can't move to value $0$ anymore so we get a run of $a$ $0$s again. And since $a\le b$, we can never move to a pile of Grundy value $1$ smaller than this new run of $0$s, so it's forced to be periodic with period $a+b$.

Comment: @saulspatz, Mark S, Suppose, I have $2$ piles $p_1, p_2$. $p_1$ contains $3$ stones and for $p_1,$ minimum stones = $1$ and maximum stones = $1$, a person can remove.  $p_2$ contains $2$ stones and for $p_2,$ minimum stones = $1$ and maximum stones = $2$, a person can remove. min. and max no. of stones are fixed. Now, as you said, Grundy number($p_1$) = $1$ and Grundy number($p_2$) = $2$.

Comment: Now, xor(1,2) = non-zero, so player 1 should be winning, right? but according to $(p_1, 1) (p_2, 2) (p_1, 1) (p_1, 1)$, player 1 is losing. here in ordered pair $(a,b)$, 'a' denotes pile and 'b' denotes removed stones and player 1 and player 2 are playing alternately and player 1 started 1st. Can you please explain what I am doing mistake ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but the first player wins by taking one stone from pile $2$.

Comment: @MarkS. Yes, that seems right.  Thanks.

Comment: @saulspatz , I have taken grundy number of the game as the xor(nim sum) operation of all the grundy numbers and getting non-zero. what does it mean ? Can you please explain the meaning of  "Grundy number of a position with multiple piles" ?

Comment: It's just what you said.  You take the take the nim sum of the Grundy numbers of the individual piles.  You did all that right.  Your only mistake is that you seem to think the position is a losing one, but as I explained in my last comment, the first player can actually win by taking one stone from pile $2$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks!. Last question, how to check  whether player 2 has a winning strategy or not if both players play optimal moves, like if xor of grundy numbers of each piles has non-zero then player 1 has winning strategy.

Comment: Player $2$ has a winning strategy if player $1$ does not.

Comment: But in the example which I have given in comments, both players have winning strategy. right ? For player 1, $(p_1,1)(p_2,1)(p_1,1)(p_1,1)(p_2,1)$ and for player 2, $(p_1,1)(p_2,2)(p_1,1)(p_1,1)$. First move is from player 1. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, you are.  How can the second player possibly have a winning strategy if the first player has a winning move?  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @saulspatz, I meant to ask, how to check, whether it is possible to defeat the player 1 or not, given the first move and any subsequent moves by the player 1. Sorry for my previous comment. I was talking about 2 different games.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.  At any point in the game you can determine who wins by computing the Grundy number of the position.  What more can there possibly be to know?  Play out the given moves, and compute the Grundy number of the resulting position.  This tells you what you want to know.

Comment: @saulspatz, yes, I can proceed from here. Thank you for the response of my all the comments and help.